# Get propertyname where attribute is on

Tags: c#, attributes

In my application I have a custom attribute calles `ResourceTargetAttribute` which looks like:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
private class ResourceTargetAttribute : Attribute
{
    public ResourceTargetAttribute(string resourceKey)
    {
        ResourceKey = resourceKey;
    }

    public string ResourceKey { get; private set; }
}
```

The usage looks like:

```
[ResourceTarget("FileNotFoundErrorText")
public string FileNotFoundErrorText { get; private set; }
```

The constructor of the `class` where the FileNotFoundErrorText-Property is defined resolves this attribute. This just works fine.

Now I was thinking about to extend the attribute to have a parameterless constructor and if this is called the name of the Property the attribute is on will automatically be used for the ResourceKey.
Therefore I've introduced a new constructor which just looks like:

```
public ResourceTargetAttribute()
{

}
```

And the usage then should look like:

```
[ResourceTarget()]
public string FileNotFoundErrorText { get; private set; }
```

And here I want to have name of the FileNotFoundErrorText-Property automatically be passed to the ResourceTarget-Attribute.

Is there a possibility to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CallerMemberNameAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx) might help you:

```
public ResourceTargetAttribute([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
  ResourceKey = propertyName;
}
```

Usage:

```
[ResourceTarget]
public string FileNotFoundErrorText { get; private set; }
```

If you get the attribute, the

```
attr.ResourceKey
```

property should contain *FileNotFoundErrorText* as value.

Otherwise I just would go the way passing the name as string as attributes are metadata applied to the members of a type, the type itself, method parameters or the assembly so you must have the original member itself to access its meta data.

Comment: Attributes are Part of the Type-System, therfore parameters need to be constant values at compile time. the optional-declaration will lead to be always null, as nothing will inject the caller-name...

Comment: About 5 minutes ago, I found this solution too :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to utilize nameof-operator:

```
[ResourceTarget(nameof(FileNotFoundErrorText)]
public string FileNotFoundErrorText { get; private set; }
```

Another approach would be to modify the code that actual examines / searches for these marker-attributes. use reflection to get the actual Property-Name on which the attribute was applied.

Maybe if you provide the mentioned "constructor-code" I could further assist.

Comment: The `FileNotFoundErrorText`-Property was just an example. I want to have a generic-way to reuse it on many properteis

Comment: Yeah sure, this is adressed by the second part of my answer. If you provide the code that "looks" for the attribute, I could further explain the solution.